# SQL query to count how many values appear N times in a column

Tags: sql

I have a table like this, but with 1mi rows:

```
+------+-----------------+
| TEAM | VISITATION DATE |
+------+-----------------+
|  1   |    02/02/2021   |
|  1   |    04/03/2021   |
|  1   |    10/04/2021   |
|  2   |    13/03/2021   |
|  3   |    01/03/2021   |
|  3   |    27/04/2021   |
|  4   |    21/02/2021   |
|  4   |    14/03/2021   |
|  4   |    01/04/2021   |
+------+-----------------+
```

And I want to know how many TEAMS were visited N times.

For instance, if I want to know how many TEAMS were visited once, the result would be 1 (because only team 2 was). If i wanted three times, result would be 2 (because both team 1 and 4 were visited three times).

It would be something like

```
SELECT COUNT(TEAM) 
FROM table 
WHERE COUNT(VISITATION DATE)=1
```

(then =2, =3, and so on)... But since I can't use COUNT after WHERE, I don't know how to do it. Can anyone help?

If it helps, it doesn't necessarily need to be connected to the visitation date. It could be "How many TEAMS appear once/twice/three times... (only considering the TEAM column)"

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you post your expected result?

Comment: @lulu check HAVING in SQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select count(team) from 
(select  team, COUNT(team) as countTeam from t group by team) 
where countTeam = 2
```

Replace 2 by the number you want.

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=a6514574fac676b031263e9a44238bf4)

Comment: Thanks so much! Your code was giving me the list of teams, so I changed it to SELECT COUNT(TEAM) FROM [...] and it worked as I wanted. Thank you again!

Comment: yes, I noticed that too and updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

With `having` we have:

```
select  
    team, 
    COUNT(team) as countTeam 
from t 
group by team
having count(team) = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `having` clause

```
select 
    team,
    COUNT(TEAM) as total_count
from table 
group by
    team
having count(team) = 1
```